# how to merge two lists into list of lists WITHOUT using zip/ map

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

First time asking a question sorry if I've missed something! I have to open a text file turn separate each word in the file and put it into a list i then have to do a count though the list and count how often each word is used and then combine these into list of lists.

so far i have managed to do all of the above except for merging them

my result for a small text file looks like -
[(['archastronomer', 'bronze', 'craft', 'craftsman', 'dactylos', 'eyes', 'fish', 'gold', 'leather', 'silver'], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])]

whereas i need ['archastronomer',1], ['bronze',1] etc

```
  #noSpaces being my list of words, wordFreq list of frequency of words
  for w in noSpaces: 

      wordFreq.append(noSpaces.count(w))


   wordList = [noSpaces] 
   freqList= [wordFreq]  #wordFreq list of frequency of words

   result= []
   for i in wordList:
      for j in freqList:
         result.append((i,j))
   print result


   mergedLists= wordList + freqList
   print(list(mergedLists))
```

I cannot use zip either, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about dictionary? You can use as a key string (word) and the value would be number if occurrence of each particular word. In this case you don't need to merge lists.

Comment: Sounds like an exercise made up by someone who doesn't know Python...

Comment: Not a good question to ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  result = []
  for w in noSpaces:
      result.append([w, noSpaces.count(w)])
```

or, if you want to keep the first part and supposing that both list have the same leght:

```
result = [ [wordList[i], freqList[i]] for i in range(len(wordList)) ]
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver it worked perfectly! I was playing around with count(w) before and no luck until now thank you!

Comment: Great, Im happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an index instead of iterating through the word list and freq list with for loops.

```
for a in range(len(wordList)):
    some_list.append(wordList[a], freqList[a])
```

Answer (score 0):

METHOD 1

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=['a','b','c']
c=[(i, j) for i, j in zip(a, b)]
print(c)
```

METHOD 2

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=['a','b','c']
print(list(zip(a, b)))
```

METHOD 3

```
e=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
e.insert(i,(a[i], b[i]))
print(e)
```

METHOD 4

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=['a','b','c']
c=[(i, j) for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```